# Angular :getting Http 400 bad request on post request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http

I have a form as follows

```
<form #demoForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(demoForm.value)" >
        <input type = "text" name ="fruit" id="add" placeholder = "Enter fruit name" ngModel>
        <input type = "submit" value = "add">
</form>
```

and following method gets invoked on form submission

```
onClickSubmit(data) {
  alert("Entered Fruitname : " + data.fruit);
  console.log(data);
  this.ob = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/demo/add", data).subscribe();

}
```

It logs `{fruit: "apple"}` in console on form submission with input value apple however I'm getting http 400 bad request on form submission.
Error I'm getting is

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Required String parameter 'fruit' is not present"
path: "/demo/add"
status: 400
```

Even though the object contains a fruit field as shown in the log, why is it still resulting in error

Spring controller is

```
    @Controller 
    @CrossOrigin(origins="*")
    @RequestMapping(path="/demo")
    public class MainController {
      @Autowired
      private FruitsRepository fruitsRepository;

      @PostMapping(path="/add") 
      public void addNewUser(@RequestParam String fruit) {
          Fruits fruits=new Fruits();
          fruits.setName(fruit);
          fruitsRepository.save(fruits);
    }
}
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestParam String fruit` expects a query parameter, not a value inside the request body. I.e. a request with the path `http://localhost:8080/demo/add?fruit=apple`, not `{"fruit": "apple"}` posted to `http://localhost:8080/demo/add`.

Comment: I'm using http Post method so query parameter won't be part of url?

Comment: Ok thanks, I should use `@RequestBody` with post request instead of `@RequestParam`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the whole object, not only t he name.
`{fruit: "apple"}` is not a string, it is an object.

To send only the fruit name (and so, a string), do the POST that way:

`this.ob = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/demo/add", data.fruit).subscribe();`

Comment: according to other answers, your server is misconfigured. A POST has a body, a GET has queryParams / requestParams

Comment: In this case only a String value is sent right? name of the string is not sent, Doesn't @RequestParam need name of the string value to retrieve it

Comment: I got it, with post request I should use `@RequestBody` not `@RequestParam`..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

define data of which type

```
     onClickSubmit({data}: {data}) {
       alert("Entered Fruitname : " + data.fruit);
       console.log( data);
       this.ob = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/demo/add", data.fruit).subscribe();

     }
```

and backend is expecting only a string of variable name as fruit soo send only fruit variable

Comment: Am I supposed to use `onClickSubmit({data.fruit}: {data.fruit:any}) ` ? I don't understand what's value here

Comment: use {data}:{data:any} and send data.fruit as input to your http.post